# Python missing DLL from installed module

Tags: python, dll, module

I got a project which consists of Python and C++. I don't understand all of it but in order to compile and run everything I run an included BAT file. I have already installed the dependencies needed. Now when I run the script, I get this:

```
    MainProcess - [INFO] os_utils: Disabling idle sleep not supported on this OS version.
world - [ERROR] launchables.world: Process Capture crashed with trace:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\work\pupil\pupil_src\launchables\world.py", line 118, in world
    from plugin_manager import Plugin_Manager
  File "C:\work\pupil\pupil_src\shared_modules\plugin_manager.py", line 15, in <module>
    from video_capture import Base_Manager, Base_Source
  File "C:\work\pupil\pupil_src\shared_modules\video_capture\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from .file_backend import FileCaptureError, FileSeekError
  File "C:\work\pupil\pupil_src\shared_modules\video_capture\file_backend.py", line 13, in <module>
    import av
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\av\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from av._core import time_base, pyav_version as __version__
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

It couldn't find pyav? But if I run:

```
C:\Users\XXX\Downloads>pip install av-0.3.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: av==0.3.1 from file:///C:/Users/XXX/Downloads/av-0.3.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl in c:\users\anton\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages
```

I already have it installed. What am  doing wrong here?

If I open ...site-packages\av__init__.py" I can see this:
`from av._core import time_base, pyav_version as __version__`

is it something here?

Comment: Which OS are you on and which project are you referring to. Could you share a link?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 and I try to compile Pupil labs from source. I have installed everything and this is the error I get when trying to run it. 
https://docs.pupil-labs.com/#python-libs it looks like it's something wrong with the av module: https://github.com/pupil-labs/pyav/releases/tag/v0.3.1

Comment: Are you running a 64bit version of python?

Comment: Yes, I am running 64 bit.

Comment: Is python in your system path?

Comment: Yep. I've tried running some other python scripts without any problems.

Comment: There is definately an issue with the `av` package. I tried downloading just that and run `python -c "import av"` after succesfull pip installation, but it threw the same error you got. Maybe it is worth trying to build that from source first

Comment: Two tools I have found useful in debugging dll issues are ProcMon from SysInternals, and DependancyWalker. In ProcMon, you can see the file handle creation as python searches for a certain dll along the path, and in DependancyWalker, you can see if - for instance - a .pyd has some dll dependancy that is not resolved

Comment: Hmm alright, I will see if I can solve it, I'm a total noob to Python and doing this on WIndows isn't ideal.

Comment: How did you install it? I have just installed it with the `conda install av -c conda-forge` method described [here](http://mikeboers.github.io/PyAV/installation.html) and it seems to import without issue. This is on a conda environment

Comment: I downloaded the whl file and installed it with pip

Comment: I suspect it is an issue with pyav finding the FFMPEG DLLs. Do you have ffmpeg installed, and viewable in the path?

Comment: Maybe, I do have FFMPEG downloaded and extracted but do  I have to compile everything again with the flag to indicate its location?

I tried installing miniConda and run the install command as the docs say but this didn't seem to have any effect, it still misses the DLLs.

Comment: I tried adding the ffmpeg flag but it didn't work: "option --ffmpeg-dir is not recognized"

Comment: I think that flag is just if your are building it from source, suspect it is part of that packages `setup.py` tool. If you have gotten pyav to install from the whl, I would just try copying the FFMPEG dll's to the python or site-packages dir, as I describe in the answer below

Comment: Hmm alright, well I got the DLLs and doing it manually is ok for me. Just which folder exactly should I put them in?
"C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\av" ?

Comment: I would put them either in "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\" or "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages"

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the module has successfully installed, but is dynamically linked against FFMPEG. You can obtain built distributions of FFMPEG from their website (https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html). They provide both statically linked and dynamically linked builds, though it is going to be the dynamically linked one that is providing the dll's you need. Looking at my own copy of PyAV, it seems that the current release version (3.4.2) is the one that it is linked against.

When you download it, it will have a name like `ffmpeg-date-build-win64-shared`. In the `bin` directory, you will find all the relevant DLLs. You can either add this directory to the `PATH`, or more easily, copy the DLLs to your python location.

Comment: Tried both suggestions and gave it a reboot, didn't resolve the problem I'm afraid. It has to be something else I guess.

Comment: Doing some digging through the Pupil Labs docs, here is an important section: https://docs.pupil-labs.com/#ffmpeg-to-pupil-external

Comment: It looks like there are a bunch of external DLL dependencies that they want you to download and put in a specific folder. The whole things looks like a mess to try and build, good luck